# Basic Python While loop compound conditional evaluation

Tags: python, while-loop, conditional-operator

In Python IDLE Shell it seems I cannot use a compound conditional expression and a while loop. I tried it within brackets too. Take these two examples:

```
k=0
m=0
while k<10 & m<10:
    print k
    k +=1
    m+=1
```

This doesn't evaluate the second condition. But if I write

```
 while k<10:
    print k
    k+=1
```

This does work. Is there a way I could achieve the first block of code with the "and" operator. I have done it in Java. Do I just need to put together "if" statements to achieve the same functionality in Python?

Comment: The answer to your question is given below by Deniz Dogan. But usually constructing `while` (or `for`) loops like this, i. e. by using a counter and incrementing it up to a certain value, is not Pythonic. You rather do a `for x in range(10)` or even better, `for item in list_of_items`, letting Python handle the iteration.

Comment: To add to Tim's comment, you can use `for idx, elem in enumerate(my_list)` to get both the 0-based "counter" in `idx` and the element at that index of the list in `elem`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&` should be `and`. `&` is the bitwise AND operator.